# Cheerio web scraping leads to multiple html elements being added together

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Im using cheerio but dont know how to access lists inside lists. so far it adds html elements not separated but adds them together. What am I doing wrong? Very helpful for any help!!!

the html:

```
...
<div classname="main">
    <div classname="content">
        <div classname="somethingElse">
             <div classname="list">
                 <div classname="item">
                   <div> 
                        <div> 
                           <ul classname="name-wrapper">
                             <li classname="name">
                               <span>
                               title
                               </span>                                 
                               <span>
                               info
                               </span>
                             </li>
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div classname="item">
                   <div> 
                        <div className="container"> 
                           <ul classname="name-wrapper">
                             <li classname="name">
                               <span>
                               other title
                               </span>                                 
                               <span>
                               other info
                               </span>
                             </li>
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div classname="item">
                  ...
                 </div>
                 ...
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
const extractContent= $ => {
    return $('.main .content .list .item')
        .map((_, item) => {
            const $item = $(item);
             return {
             ...
             title: $item.find('.name-wrapper span:nth-of-type(1)').text(),
             info:  $item.find('.name-wrapper span:nth-of-type(2)').text(),
             createdAt: new Date()
                   ...
                }
            }).toArray();
    }
```

I receive for title:

> title other title

I receive for info:

> info other info

Comment: Try `[...$item.find('.name span')].map(e => $(e).text())`